# Is it possible to duplicate a UDP unicast stream with iptables?

Tags: iptables, udp, video-streaming

I have a proprietary system which transmit a udp video stream from unit #1 (192.168.1.1) to unit #2 (.1.2). I can't make changes to this system, and I'm trying to clone this udp stream so I can access it in a different program. This program will do stuff with the video and send it out again as a multicast stream.

I'm hoping to do this using a Linux machine (running Ubuntu Server 12.04 now) with three network cards. By connecting unit #1 and #2 to two of the network cards (eth0 and eth1) in the Linux machine and using bridge, I've got them communicating. My /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The external interface
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0

# The bridge interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
  bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

This works, and by using tcpdump I've confirmed that the udp packets are arriving from #1 and are heading towards #2 at port 6000.

The next step I hope will work is to use iptables to clone all udp packets comming from 192.168.1.1 going to port 6000 at #2. I'm not very familiar with iptables, but after reading on line and the manual I thought this would work:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp -s 192.168.1.1/32 --dport 6000 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.10.2
```

The rule is applied successfully, but it doesn't work. If I use tcpdump to monitor eth3 I don't see the packets there.

I'd like to grab this stream, work on it and send it out as a multicast on the .10.2 interface.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 4):

The packets never reach eth3 as 192.168.10.2 is the machine itself. Also the duplicated packets still have the destincation ip-address 192.168.1.2. You need to TEE them to a machine in 192.168.10.0/24 for example 192.168.10.254 so that the duplicates actually get routed over eth3.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 6000 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.10.254
```

Then you also need to DNAT them to 192.168.10.254, so you can read the stream on 192.168.10.254 and send it out via multicasting.

Either on 192.168.10.254 itself:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 6000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.254:6000
```

Or still on 192.168.10.2 before the packets are leaving eth3:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth3 -p udp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 6000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.254:6000
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what you've explained would send the packets to a different machine (.10.254). I would like to avoid this extra machine, and just do this internally on one machine. If I set the gateway to 127.0.0.1, would that work=?

Comment: The gateway is just a next hop the destination still remains 192.168.1.2 and you are not able to DNAT the duplicated packets on the machine "teeing" them. So 127.0.0.1 will not work either.

Comment: So I can't do what I'm trying to using just one machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with a little program which used libpcap to read the contents of the UDP packets.  It sent copies of these packets to another destination.  (Which could be on the same machine.)